# Set size of window to exact pixels, and place via x, y coordinates

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript

I would like to create a tool that allows you to set windows to exact sizes on the pixel scale to be able to have more precise screen divisions.

For example, if I had four Terminal windows (and I didn't have something cool like iTerm to do this for me), I'd like to be able to set each one to 1/2 screen height and 1/2 screen width, and people to position them via x, y coordinates so that they took up the entire screen, and exactly one fourth of them individually.

Can this be done using applescript?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, this can be done using AppleScript. Read [this link](http://ithug.com/2007/09/applescript-moving-and-resizing-windows/) to understand the code and then try and implement it yourself for your specific situation.

[Here](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/firsttutorial/11.html) is another link that describes the bounds of a window in detail.

### Example:

```
tell application "Finder" to set the bounds of the front window to {24, 96, 524, 396}
```

would set the Finder window to be in the top left corner.

### Mac App Store- BetterSnapTool:

Note: I would check out [BetterSnapTool](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12). It does exactly what you want for $1.99. I use it myself and I find it invaluable, especially at such a low price.

Comment: Also, is there a preset variable of the screen resolution?

Comment: No, but you can run `system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | grep Resolution` in iTerm to get the screen resolution. Or open up `System Profiler` and it should tell you. One more thing to try is to use the bounds property of a window in AppleScript: you can make a Finder window open completely (drag to fill entire screen) and then run `tell application "Finder" to get the bounds of the front window` in AppleScript and it will return the bounds, which represents the area of the window.

Comment: How do I tell it to go to the full bounds of the csreen if I don't know what they are?

Comment: If you expand the Finder window so that you know it is at its maximum width and height of your screen and then execute `tell application "Finder" to get the bounds of the front window`, this will return the area of the window which is the full bounds of the screen. It will return it in this format: {72, 90, 512, 481}.

Comment: `37:43: execution error: Keine Berechtigung zum Senden von Apple-Events an Finder. (-1743)`

Answer (score 9):

I found a few Apple scripts online, but they all seemed to be outdated and no longer worked. I managed to combine them into the following script, which worked for me:

```
set theApp to "Terminal"
set appWidth to 1280
set appHeight to 800

tell application "System Events" to tell application process theApp
    tell window 1
        set position to {50, 50}
        set size to {appWidth, appHeight}
    end tell
end tell
```

There are couple of caveats:

- If the desired `appHeight` is greater than the main displays's height, the resizing won't quite work. I ended up setting my external monitor as a main display.
- You need to add accessibility permissions for the "Script Editor" app as displayed below:

[image]

Comment: Which access rights have to be activated exactly?

Comment: @DarwinOSX I added a screenshot to the my response showing which permission is needed.